# What is the most convenient way to initialize a static vector inside a class?

Tags: c++, vector, static, initialization, c++11

If I want to initialize a vector inside a class, for example:

```
class A {
  private:
    static std::vector<double> label_map;
};
```

If I want to initialize this static vector, what is the best way to do? I've read in some other posts saying that starting from GCC 4.4, it supports new features in C++0x and we can directly use

```
static std::vector<double> label_map = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

However seems it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is the question - how to get a C++ compiler? Download it from the GCC website...

Comment: @KerrekSB: My GCC version is 4.6.2, so I think it's not the problem of the compiler.

Comment: Well, are you adding `-std=c++0x` to the command line?

Comment: It's better to do `label_map { 1, 2, 3, 4 }` than `label_map = {1, 2, 3, 4}` because the former initialises the vector with `1, 2, 3, 4` while the latter creates a temp vector and uses the vector copy constructor to make `label_map`

Comment: @KerrekSB: seems cannot work even after I add -std=c++0x...

Comment: @KerrekSB: It goes something like g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"tsv2bin.d" -MT"tsv2bin.d" -o "tsv2bin.o" "../tsv2bin.cc"

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It produces the error message of "../dataset/dataset.h:18:30: error: function definition does not declare parameters"

Comment: @derekhh no no, you put `static std::vector<double> label_map;` in the class definition, and in the .cpp file you put `std::vector<double> A::label_map { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Thanks, problem solved. So I cannot initialize a variable inside a class when declaring it in C++? Since I think we can do it in C#...

Comment: @derekhh you are correct, the only way you can do that is if the static variable is `const` and of integral type, and you never take the address of it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Thanks for the nice clarification. :)

Comment: Not directly. C++11 allows variable initialization inside the class, so long it's *either* non-static *or* static and const.

Comment: @Xeo: I think if it's `static` it has to be `constexpr` in general (i.e. for non-integral types).

Comment: @Kerrek: Derp, that second part should've been "static, const and of integral type".

Comment: @SethCarnegie : Technically, if you 'ODR-use' it, which isn't limited to taking its address.

Comment: @Seth no it does not create a temporary vector. Both directly initialize the vector variable. The only difference is that the `=` form forbids using explicit constructors, nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So... wrapping up:

```
// thefile.cpp

class Foo
{
    static std::vector<int> v;
};

std::vector<int> Foo::v { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Compile with `g++ -std=c++0x -c -o thefile.o thefile.cpp # ...`.

Comment: Why the second pair of curly brackets?

Comment: @Xeo: Hm, the preferred uniform initialization syntax? Also works: `v{1,2,3}`, `v = {1,2,3}`, and `v({1,2,3})`. I always imagine `v { il }`, where `il` is an existing initialization list, inside some complex class constructor... matter of taste I suppose.

Comment: Whoa... I would have never guessed. Is this standards compliant? EDIT: NVM, I saw the c++0x in the command line.

Comment: This will not compile. You need to omit one level of braces.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Ah, another brace bug. I submitted one or two of those myself a while ago... I'm not sure; do you have some standard reference why this isn't OK? Looks to me like it should be identitical to `v({1,2,3})`, which calls the IL constructor?

Comment: @KerrekSB i provided a spec reference in the GCC PR. It is not identical to `v({1, 2, 3})`, because that one can use the copy/move constructors. Because 13.3.3.1p4 does not apply the restriction to `v({1, 2, 3})`, but to `v{{1, 2, 3}}`. The former uses OR-context 13.3.1.3, the latter uses OR-context 13.3.1.7.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: OK, I trust you :-) (There's a limit to how much I can think about braces in one day. Reason I didn't pass Lisp class.)

Comment: @Kerrek please view the bugreport again. I'm sorry for the noise :)